# edit added data to sublcassed QSqlQueryModel?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqlquerymodel

i want to display in a QlistView the index and the file name, so i subclassed QSqlQueryModel to override the data() method but i'm always getting None, it seems like i'm displaying the data befor adding it or some thing like that here is the concerned part of my code :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *

import sys, os
import pathlib

CURRENT_PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

connection = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
connection.setDatabaseName("medias.sqlite")
connection.open()
print(connection.open())
createTableQuery = QSqlQuery()
createTableQuery.exec(
    """
    CREATE TABLE fichiers (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        path VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
    )
    """
)
print(connection.tables())

class PlaylistModel(QSqlQueryModel):
    def __init__(self, playlist,*args, **kwargs):
        super(PlaylistModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.playlist = playlist or  [[]]
    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            try:
                text = self.playlist[index.row()][1]
            except IndexError:
                text = None
            return text  # always getting None

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.play_list = []
        self.setGeometry(900,180,800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Media Display")
        self.model = PlaylistModel(self.play_list)
        self.model.setQuery("SELECT path FROM fichiers")
        
        self.listview = QListView()
        self.listview.setModel(self.model)
        self.listview.setModelColumn(1)
        self.main_layout()
        self.DbConnect()

    def DbConnect(self):
        self.connection = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.connection.setDatabaseName("medias.sqlite")
        self.connection.open()
        createTableQuery = QSqlQuery()
        createTableQuery.exec(
            """ CREATE TABLE fichiers (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            path VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
            )
            """
            )
        self.model.setQuery("SELECT path FROM fichiers")
        return True

    def addToPlaylist(self):
        self.play_list.clear()
        model = self.listview.model()
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            index = model.index(row , 0)
            item = model.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
            self.play_list.append(item)
        print('the playlist',self.play_list)
    def addImage(self):
        fichier_base, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'select video', QDir.homePath(),"Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg *.jpeg)")

        if fichier_base:
            query = QSqlQuery()
            query.prepare("""INSERT INTO fichiers (path) VALUES (?)""")
            query.addBindValue(fichier_base)
            if query.exec_():
                last_query = self.model.query().executedQuery()
                self.model.setQuery("")
                self.model.setQuery(last_query)

            else:
                print(query.lastError().text())
      
    def clearDb(self):
        query = QSqlQuery(self.connection)
        if self.connection.open():
            query.exec("DELETE FROM fichiers")
            query.clear()
            last_query = self.model.query().executedQuery()
            self.model.setQuery("")
            self.model.setQuery(last_query)

    def main_layout(self):

        self.add_img_btn = QPushButton("Add image ")
        self.add_img_btn.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.add_img_btn.clicked.connect(self.addImage)

        self.clear_db_btn = QPushButton("clear DB")
        self.clear_db_btn.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.clear_db_btn.clicked.connect(self.clearDb)

        self.refresh_btn = QPushButton("refresh")
        self.refresh_btn.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.refresh_btn.clicked.connect(self.addToPlaylist)

        group_btns = QHBoxLayout()

        main_app = QVBoxLayout()

        main_app.addWidget(self.listview)
        main_app.addLayout(group_btns)

        group_btns.addWidget(self.add_img_btn)
        group_btns.addWidget(self.clear_db_btn)
        group_btns.addWidget(self.refresh_btn)

        vboxlay = QHBoxLayout()
        vboxlay.addLayout(main_app)

        widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        widget.setLayout(vboxlay)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app= QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setStyleSheet('background-color:#fff;')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

on a previous app i subclassed the QAbstractListModel Class and i did it like that

```
class PlaylistModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, playlist, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlaylistModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.playlist = playlist

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            media = self.playlist.media(index.row())
            print('mediaaaaaaa', media )
            print('plaaaaaylist', self.playlist )
            name_video = media.canonicalUrl().fileName()
            i = index.row() + 1
            return f"{i} -          {name_video}"

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self.playlist.mediaCount()
```

Comment: please provide a [MRe]

Comment: sorry i edited the code above i have done some mistakes, now it's working thankyou @eyllanesc

Comment: Do you still have the problem that your post points out? If you no longer have the problem then you should delete your post

Comment: i still have the problem, when i override the QSqlQueryModel class i'm not able to display my data i get None instead

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is, what do you hope to get by override the data method? Why do you need to modify it? I think you have an XY problem. From what I see is that by default the QSqlQueryModel shows the path of the file and you want it to show the index, something like `{number of row} -       {path_of_file}`, am I correct?

Comment: yes exactly, how can i do it ? please

Comment: The add_img_btn button is used to add the path to the table, the clear_db_btn button is used to delete all the paths but what I don't understand is what is the refresh_btn button for?

Comment: it's a button to call the addToplaylist() function to get all the items on a simple python list

Comment: I do not say how you implement it but for what it serves the user, I see that you copy one list to another that I see unnecessary and silly.

Comment: ah ! sorry that's because i'm trying to display this list to a vlc playlist  player

Comment: I do not understand you, well, I will not implement that logic (it will be part of your job), but I will focus on pointing out the correct tools

Comment: and this is the only solution that i found to do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be taken into account:

- If you are going to show information from a table then you must use a QSqlTableModel. QSqlQueryModel is a read-only model whose objective is to show very particular query information. On the other hand, QSqlTableModel has several methods to handle the tables.
- If you are going to modify how the information of the model is shown in a view then you must use a delegate. This makes the modifications more flexible since you can have different models applying the same modifications to the views.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QFileDialog,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QListView,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QStyledItemDelegate,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


def create_connection():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("medias.sqlite")
    if not db.open():
        print(db.lastError().text())
        return False

    q = QSqlQuery()
    if not q.exec(
        """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fichiers (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        path VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
    )
    """
    ):
        print(q.lastError().text())
        return False
    print(db.tables())
    return True


class StyledItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.text = f"{index.row() + 1} -          {index.data()}"


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.play_list = []
        self.setGeometry(900, 180, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Media Display")

        self.model = QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable("fichiers")
        self.model.select()

        self.listview = QListView()
        delegate = StyledItemDelegate(self.listview)
        self.listview.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        self.listview.setModel(self.model)
        self.listview.setModelColumn(1)

        self.init_ui()

    def addImage(self):
        fichier_base, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, "select video", QDir.homePath(), "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg *.jpeg)"
        )

        if fichier_base:
            rec = self.model.record()
            rec.setValue("path", fichier_base)
            self.model.insertRecord(-1, rec)
            self.model.select()

    def clearDb(self):
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.exec("DELETE FROM fichiers")
        self.model.select()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.add_img_btn = QPushButton("Add image ")
        self.add_img_btn.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.add_img_btn.clicked.connect(self.addImage)

        self.clear_db_btn = QPushButton("clear DB")
        self.clear_db_btn.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.clear_db_btn.clicked.connect(self.clearDb)

        self.refresh_btn = QPushButton("refresh")
        self.refresh_btn.setFixedWidth(150)

        group_btns = QHBoxLayout()

        main_app = QVBoxLayout()

        main_app.addWidget(self.listview)
        main_app.addLayout(group_btns)

        group_btns.addWidget(self.add_img_btn)
        group_btns.addWidget(self.clear_db_btn)
        group_btns.addWidget(self.refresh_btn)

        widget = QWidget()
        vboxlay = QHBoxLayout(widget)
        vboxlay.addLayout(main_app)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    if not create_connection():
        sys.exit(-1)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setStyleSheet("background-color:#fff;")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ididn"t know that